# In a stored procedure how to run a query and conditionally do something

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

How would I do this in a stored procedure (SQL 2005):

```
count = select count(*) from table1 where line like '%success%'
if count > 0:
   delete from table1 where not line like '%success%'
```

Thanks for any help.  My google skills are really failing me today :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So if there are any rows where `line` is like success then delete any rows where `line` is not like success?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * from table1 where line like '%success%')
   delete from table1 where line NOT like '%success%'
```

Answer (score 5):

I would write that this way

```
if exist (select 1 from table1 where line like '%success%')
begin
    delete from table1 where line not like '%success%'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not keep the check at all. What is the purpose of that check?

Just use the delete query along with the where clause.

Comment: I assume the table is a log of some sort, so if the process ended without a "success" message you can find out what went wrong. On the other hand, when there is a "success" message he's not interested in the other messages, only that it was successful.
That's my guess.